# My @RequestBody is empty - SpringBoot - Postman

Tags: spring-boot

I test a call on postman for a login. But my request doesn't match with RequestBody.
I want to test a jwt authentification.

```java
package com.test.jwt.api.controller;

import com.test.jwt.api.entity.AuthRequest;
import com.test.jwt.api.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class WelcomeController {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome !!";
    }


    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public String generateToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
        try {
            
            System.out.println("Appel generate Token"+authRequest.getUserName()+"/"+authRequest.getPassword());
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUserName(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("inavalid username/password");
        }
        return jwtUtil.generateToken(authRequest.getUserName());
      //  return "toto";
    }
}
```

My class authRequest

```java
package com.test.jwt.api.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
public class AuthRequest {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    
    public AuthRequest(String username, String password) {
        System.out.println("TEste");

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public AuthRequest() {
        System.out.println("TEste2");
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public Object getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @JsonProperty(value = "username")
    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    @JsonProperty(value = "password")
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

My Json

```json
{
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "pwd1"
}
```

My log. The data steal empty.

TEste2
Appel generate Tokennull/null

Do you know where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That POJO - `AuthRequest` programmatically returns `null` from both its getters. You also have a mixture of Lombok `@Data` on there as well as hand made getters, that use different names to the fields, and JSON annotations.

If you're using Lombok then add `@GettersAndSetters` to the class and remove all the manually created ones. Similarly, remove the constructors altogether. You shouldn't need a parameterised constructor, the default constructor plus the setters should be enough.

The root cause of this seems to be a case of you adding additional implementation on top of pretty standard getters and setters which would easily marshall in and out of JSON.